# Power of a Discrete time signal

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis

I was learning on power of signal and i went through different formula in internet .

I get different results when i go through internet .

[image]

But in other site average power is  written as

[image]

I dont know if both are different formula for different condition .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The power of a discrete-time signal $x[n]$ is given by

$$P_x=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2N+1}\sum_{n=-N}^{N}|x[n]|^2$$

which is identical to the first formula in your question. The second formula is wrong and does not even make any sense due to the infinite limits of the sum.

I'd advise you to use text books or high-quality internet resources such as [MIT OpenCourseWare](https://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm).

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to use a riemann sum?$$P_x=\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^{N}|x[n]|^2 \Delta t$$ where T is the length of the symbol and $\Delta t$ is the sampling interval

Comment: @LewisKelsey: This *is* a Riemann sum, because $\Delta t/(2T)=1/(2N+1)$.

Comment: damn, I didn't see it

Answer (score 0):

Both formulas are the same .. It's just that one of them is divide by 2N (number of points from -N till N excluding 0) and the other by 2N+1  (number of points from -N till N including 0). 
But that doesn't matter when N goes to infinity given that x[0] is bounded.

Comment: And what about the limits $\pm\infty$ in the second formula?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the second expression for power is not strictly professional, though I know it is trying to do the same as the first one. Please stick to the first version which should appear in any good textbooks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by an expression being "professional". It can either be correct or wrong, and the second formula is simply wrong.

Comment: @MattL. You are right. It is a wrong one.